# Return updated HTML table values into Views.Py

Tags: javascript, html, django

Hi I have an html table that has values that is originally pulled from a database.  They are editable and if the user updates the value, I want to be able return the updated values to Views.py and then from there save the updated value back into the database.  For example, I have the table below:

```
<table>

            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>F</th>
            </tr>

                {% for x in VAR %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>Yes</td>
                        <td>{{ x }}</td>
                        <td><div contenteditable>{{ x.a }}</div></td>
                        <td><div contenteditable>{{ x.b}}</div></td>
                        <td><div contenteditable>{{ x.c}}</div></td>
                    </tr>

                {% endfor %}

</table>
```

If they update x.a for example, I want to return the new value to Views.

When I try a POST request, I return a blank value / empty list.  How do I return the updated values into my Views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some javascript for this.  Set an `input` change handler for all contenteditable divs and have it pack the data into a `POST` request.  In jquery, this would be approximately:

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('input', function(){
    $.post('/setData', {k:this.id, v:this.innerText});
});
```

(Written from memory -- might not be exactly right).